# Change detection not working on angular elements + NgRx

Tags: angular, ngrx, web-component, custom-element, angular-elements

I was trying to work with custom elements + NgRX and tried to integrate the custom element in an angularjs app. Whenever from my angularjs app I am calling the custom element exposed method change detection is not happening.

Calling code in angular js
`const customElement= angular.element('hello-ce')[0];
 customElement.refreshSettingProgressValue(settingsPage);`

Exposed method in Angular 7 + @ngrx/store + Custom Elements:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoading$ = this.store.pipe(select(landingPageQuery.getLoading));
    this.categories$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(landingPageQuery.getAllLandingPage)
    );
  }
  @Input()
  public refreshSettingProgressValue = function (this: CompType, settingCategoryCode: string) {
    this.categories$.pipe(
      mergeMap(categories => categories),
      map(category => category.settings),
      mergeMap(settings => settings),
      filter(setting => setting.settingCodeType.code === settingCategoryCode),
      take(1)
    ).subscribe({
      next: (setting) => {
        this.store.dispatch(new ResetSettingsProgressValue(setting));
        this.store.dispatch(new LoadSettingsProgressValue(setting));
      }
    })
  }.bind(this);
```

I tried calling the _refreshSettingProgressValue _ inside Angular7 app on click of a dummy button and everything works but when I call it outside Angular context I am not able to see the changes in UI.
P.S *LoadSettingsProgressValue* has an effect where we call some api. I see the call is also happening and reducer is also updating the state but change detection doesn't seem to kick in.

I have already tried [ngzone-element-strartergy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elements-zone-strategy) but it didnt resolve my issue

```
  ngDoBootstrap(): void {
    const elements: any[] = [
      [HelloWorldComponent, 'hello-ce'],
    ];
    for (const [component, name] of elements) {
      const strategyFactory = new ElementZoneStrategyFactory(component, this.injector);
      const el = createCustomElement(component, { injector: this.injector, strategyFactory  });
      customElements.define(name, el);
    }
  }
```

I believe we can call changeDetection explicitly but with ngrx how and where can we do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my project and it got solved using *this.cd.detectChanges();* when data must be to be updated like this example:

```
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  private setState(key, value) {
    this.state = { ...this.state, [key]: value };
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
```

Source: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular-elements-advanced-techniques/

Answer (score 0):

Finally could get the change detected by running inside ngZone like below:

```
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.store.dispatch(new ResetSettingsProgressValue(setting));
        this.store.dispatch(new LoadSettingsProgressValue(setting));
  });
```

Tried firing change detection on every emit value after

```
    this.categories$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(landingPageQuery.getAllLandingPage),
      tap(_ => this.changeDetectionRef.detectChanges())
    );
```

but it doesn't work!!!. If anyone has any better solution please post.
Thanks